# Error ERR_REQUIRE_ESM require() of ES Module /node_modules/swiper/swiper-vue.mjs not supported

Tags: frontend, vuejs3, swiper.js

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /Users/macbook/Projects/relocate-front/node_modules/swiper/swiper-vue.mjs not supported.
Instead change the require of /Users/macbook/Projects/relocate-front/node_modules/swiper/swiper-vue.mjs to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.

Swiper.js v11.0.4
please help me solve the problem

I tried deleting type:module in package.json in the swiper package, tried to downgrade version of swiper